# below listener configuration not working in web.xml for spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web.xml

The below ContextListener is my self-defined class and below is the code for it and the medthods defined in are not getting called .i;m not sure what internally is happening.please help me on this

```
package com.apalya.promo.properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ContextListener {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class);

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
   logger.info("       !!!!!!!!PromoTv module is Going To Be Deployed     
!!!!!!!!       ");
   System.out.println("       !!!!!!!!PromoTv module is Going To Be 
Deployed !!!!!!!!       ");
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ServerProperties.setConfigMap();
        ServerProperties.setDbQueriesMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.info("       @@@@@@@@@@@  Error In ServletContextListener 
Class  @@@@@@@@@  :: " + e);
    }
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    logger.info("       ++++++++++ PromoTv module  is Going to Stop 
++++++++++++       ");
   System.out.println("       ++++++++++ PromoTv module  is Going to Stop 
++++++++++++       ");

}


}
```

`
and here is my web.xml file where i configured listener class for my user-defined class and it looks like it is not getting invoked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com
/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<listener>
        <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
          <listener-class>
            com.apalya.promo.properties.ContextListener
          </listener-class>
</listener>  

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: listerner not working in above web.xml

Comment: Valid listener class should implement [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html?is-external=true) interface. Yours doesn't, which is why it's not working. There also must be a message about it in server logs at startup, that you seem to have missed.